# How does one modify the package contents output by WooCOmmerce on the checkout page, without modifying plugin code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, if I have several shipping methods and suppliers and someone orders several products from one or multiple suppliers, each shipping method will list the items as part of that shipping per supplier, so there is more than one shipping list, e.g. Shipping, Shipping 2 and so on. The items under each shipping block are separated by a comma.

[image: screenshot of shipping package]

What I want to do is make change the markup so that the items are output as a list. It could be as simple as changing the comma to a line break tag or more involved if I could actually filter the list to generate list tags and all that. Honestly, it doesn't matter, I just want to know if anyone knows what the correct way to do this is because I can't seem to find any hook or filter that even touches this.

I can see where the data is being inserted in the Woocommerce template file /plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php

on line 76

```
<?php echo '<p class="woocommerce-shipping-contents"><small>' . esc_html( $package_details ) . '</small></p>'; ?>
```

But the section that sets the comma separation is not on a template file it is located in the file /plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php

on line 229

```
 'package_details'          => implode( ', ', $product_names ),
```

It is part of the function

```
/**
* Get shipping methods.
*/

 function wc_cart_totals_shipping_html() {
 $packages = WC()->shipping()->get_packages();
 $first    = true;

 foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
    $chosen_method = isset( WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] ) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] : '';
    $product_names = array();

    if ( count( $packages ) > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) {
            $product_names[ $item_id ] = $values['data']->get_name() . ' &times;' . $values['quantity'];
        }
        $product_names = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_details_array', $product_names, $package );
    }

    wc_get_template(
        'cart/cart-shipping.php',
        array(
            'package'                  => $package,
            'available_methods'        => $package['rates'],
            'show_package_details'     => count( $packages ) > 1,
            'show_shipping_calculator' => is_cart() && apply_filters( 
            'woocommerce_shipping_show_shipping_calculator', $first, $i, $package ),
            'package_details'          => implode( ', ', $product_names ),
            /* translators: %d: shipping package number */
            'package_name'             => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', ( ( $i + 1 ) > 1 ) ? sprintf( _x( 'Shipping %d', 'shipping packages', 'woocommerce' ), ( $i + 1 ) ) : _x( 'Shipping', 'shipping packages', 'woocommerce' ), $i, $package ),
            'index'                    => $i,
            'chosen_method'            => $chosen_method,
            'formatted_destination'    => WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $package['destination'], ', ' ),
            'has_calculated_shipping'  => WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping(),
        )
    );

    $first = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution is by overwriting the [cart-shipping.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php#L7) template file, since in the template file the output from `$package_details` is [passed](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php#L76) via the `esc_html()` function. 
In other words, if you could adjust this at all, the customizations would be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following 7uc1f3r's suggestion and overrode the template. I am on mobile so I can't type all the code I used right now, but I basically set the $package_details variable equal to itself with the esc_html function, then again with a string replace to replace the commas with breaks. Then I had the original function echo the variable itself without the esc_html function to keep the breaks intact.